# After selector in css doens´t show in all elements and JQquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having two problems, that i would like you to help me in this case,  when i try to apply this css for all div elements it doesnt happen:

This is the html:

```
 <div class="thumb clickSeleccion" id="seleccionImagen">
   <a class="thumbnail "  style="margin-bottom:10px;height: 145px;width: 145px"></a>
</div>

 <div class="thumb clickSeleccion" id="seleccionImagen-1">
   <a class="thumbnail "  style="margin-bottom:10px;height: 145px;width: 145px"></a>
</div>
```

this is the css.

```
.clickSeleccion::after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: x-large;
    content: "\f058";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 98px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}
```

just take one element and not all, theres something im doing wrong, can you help?,

2. Second problem: when i click this element, the actual class has to change to remove the arrow

this is de JQuery code:

```
 $('.thumb').click(function() {                
       if($( "#"+this.id ).hasClass('clickSeleccion')){
            $( "#"+this.id ).removeClass( 'clickSeleccion' ).addClass( 'clickSeleccionNO' );
        }else{
            $( "#"+this.id ).removeClass( 'clickSeleccionNO' ).addClass( 'clickSeleccion' );
        }
    });
```

Also this is the link where you can access this code:

LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/95tngef5/

thank you. and sorry about my english, i might be not explaning well.

Comment: As a note, in your `if { ... }` section of your jQuery, you may be able to simplify things by doing `$("#"+this.id).toggleClass('clickSeleccion clickSeleccionNO')`.

Comment: Thank you @cjl750 you´re completely right, i made the change to toggleClass thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the parent element a `position` for `position: absolute` to work as you intend. It is fixed if you add `.clickSeleccion { position: relative; }`.

See [positioning context on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Positioning_contexts) for details.

```js
$('.thumb').click(function() {
  if ($("#" + this.id).hasClass('clickSeleccion')) {
    $("#" + this.id).removeClass('clickSeleccion').addClass('clickSeleccionNO');
  } else {
    $("#" + this.id).removeClass('clickSeleccionNO').addClass('clickSeleccion');
  }
});
```

```css
.clickSeleccion {
  position: relative;
}

.clickSeleccion::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: x-large;
  content: "\f058";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 98px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.thumb {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb clickSeleccion" id="seleccionImagen">
  <a class="thumbnail " style="margin-bottom:10px;height: 145px;width: 145px"></a>
</div>

<div class="thumb clickSeleccion" id="seleccionImagen-1">
  <a class="thumbnail " style="margin-bottom:10px;height: 145px;width: 145px"></a>
</div>
```